# FEM diffusion: inaccurate results small time steps

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, diffusion

I wrote some FEM code and found some strange results when using a very small time step. So, I decided to analyze the discrete equations.

Consider the following linear diffusion problem in 1 dimension:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
\end{equation}

where `k` is a positive constant.

I will solve this problem on a 1D mesh of 2 linear elements, that is: 3 nodes located at $x_0$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ where $x_{i+1} = x_i + h$ and $h$ is the spacing (a positive constant). The first and last node constitute the Dirichlet boundary (so, there is no Neumann boundary). The initial and boundary conditions read:

\begin{align}
u(t = 0, x) &= u_i \\\
u(t, x_0) &= \hat{u}_0 \\\
u(t, x_2) &= \hat{u}_2
\end{align}

Using the classic Galerkin method (with shape functions $(1 - \xi, \xi)$), discretization of the spatial domain yields:

\begin{equation}
\frac{h}{6} 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\\
1 & 4 & 1 \\\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\dot{\bf{u}} + \frac{k}{h}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \bf{u} = 0
\end{equation}

where $\bf{u}$ is the nodal vector $(u_0, u_1, u_2)^T$ and $\dot{\bf{u}}$ is the derivative of $\bf{u}$ with respect to time.

Using the $\theta$-method for the discretization of the time domain, we get:

\begin{equation}
\left[
\frac{h}{6 \Delta t} 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\\
1 & 4 & 1 \\\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} + \theta\frac{k}{h}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right] {\bf{u}^{n+1}}\\\
= \\\
\left[
\frac{h}{6 \Delta t} 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\\
1 & 4 & 1 \\\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} - (1 - \theta)\frac{k}{h}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right] \bf{u}^n
\end{equation}

where $\Delta t$ is the time step and super-indexes refer to the time, such that $t_{n+1} = t_n + \Delta t$.

Finally, defining $\alpha = \frac{k \Delta t}{h^2}$ and imposing the boundary conditions, we get:

\begin{align}
u_0^{n+1} &= \hat{u}_0 \\\
u_1^{n+1} &= \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3} + 2\theta \alpha}
\left[
\left(\frac{1}{6} - \alpha \theta \right)\left(u_0^n - \hat{u}_0\right) +
\left(\frac{1}{6} - \alpha \theta \right)\left(u_2^n - \hat{u}_2\right) + \\\
\alpha \left( u_0^n + u_2^n \right) +
\left(\frac{2}{3} - 2\alpha (1 -  \theta)\right)u_1^n
\right]\\\
u_2^{n+1} &= \hat{u}_2
\end{align}

where sub-indexes refer to the nodes.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that:

\begin{align}
u_i &= 0 \\\
\hat{u}_0 &> 0 \\\
\hat{u}_2 &= 0
\end{align}

Now, the solution at time $t_{n+1}$ is given by:

\begin{align}
u_0^{n+1} &= \hat{u}_0 \\\
u_1^{n+1} &= \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3} + 2\theta \alpha}
\left[
\left(\frac{1}{6} - \alpha \theta \right)\left(u_0^n - \hat{u}_0\right) +
\alpha u_0^n + \left(\frac{2}{3} - 2\alpha (1 -  \theta)\right)u_1^n
\right]\\\
u_2^{n+1} &= \hat{u}_2
\end{align}

Now, under those conditions, we know that the value of $u_1$, at any time, lies in the interval $\left[ 0, \frac{\hat{u}_0}{2} \right]$, and in particular, when $\Delta t$ tends to $\infty$, it is easy to show that $u_1$ tends to $\frac{\hat{u}_0}{2}$.

However, we can see that the solution $u^{n+1}_1$ can take negative values if $\alpha$ is small enough (which, for instance, can be achieved by choosing a small enough time step $\Delta t$). This can be easily seen when calculating the solution at node 1 at time $t_1$ (recall that the initial solution was chosen to be 0 $\forall x \in [0,2]$):

\begin{equation}
u_1^1 = -\frac{\left(\frac{1}{6} - \alpha \theta \right) \hat{u}_0}{\frac{2}{3} + 2\theta \alpha}
\end{equation}

If we choose a time step such that $\alpha < \frac{1}{6\theta}$, then $u^1_1$ becomes negative, which is clearly an inaccurate result.

To summarize, this problem comes from the difference $u_0^n - \hat{u}_0$ and may arise in the following situations:

1. The boundary value at node $0$ differs from the initial solution at node $0$.
2. The boundary value at node $0$ at time $t_n$ differs from the boundary value at node $0$ at time $t_{n+1}$.

Both points are actually equivalent. So, here are 2 questions:

1. Is this a known problem? I guess it is, but I've had trouble finding info on it.
2. If it is not a known problem, where did I go wrong? Did I apply the boundary values wrongly?

This second question made me calculate the solution $u^{n+1}_1$ when $\alpha$ tends to $0$:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\alpha \to 0} u^{n+1}_1 = \frac{\frac{1}{6}\left(u_0^n - \hat{u}_0\right) + \frac{2}{3}u^n_1}{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{equation}

The limit should be equal to $u^n_1$, which is only true if $u_0^n = \hat{u}_0$. So, here goes another question:

When applying a boundary value on node $0$ at time $t_{n+1}$, do I need to set $u_0^n$ to that same value as well? This would eliminate the problem of having negative values, but am I still solving the same problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you find is indeed correct. It is known that positivity is lost if very small time steps are chosen, see

https://doi.org/10.1515/cmam-2015-0018

This loss of positivity happens even for semi-discrete scheme.

The analysis for 1-d case is given in section 6 of this paper.

Comment: @mfnx I did not try to give a detailed answer since it is not a simple answer, and the paper explains it well. If you think your question is answered by the analysis in the paper, you can close this by accepting my answer.

Comment: part of it is answered. I'd like to have an answer to the last questions